# How to pass a variable name in cd command linux

Tags: linux, shell, get, sftp

I have a connection to a SFTP in a shell script but when i try to get some files passing variable name but sends me an error. My code:

```
set date_file_format [timestamp -format %C%y%m%d]
#some code
expect "sftp>"
send "mget /home/dir/*$date_file_format*.dat /home2/user/dir2 \r"
```

date_file_format is = 20140117

I want to get all files that contains "20140117" and extension .dat using a wildcard *$date_file_format*.dat

This is the error:

```
sftp> usage: send [args] string
    while executing
"send "mget /home/dir/*$date_file_format*.dat /home2/user/dir2 \r""
    (file "./bash.sh" line 15)
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Start your script with ‘#!/bin/bash -vx‘

Comment: This is an expect-script?

Comment: Your title and tags have very little in common with your actual question.

Comment: Yes, it's an expect-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your are trying to execute an expect program using a shell interpreter. expect is a different language and must be executed using the `expect` interpreter.

Comment: How can i execute it using the expect interpreter if i have an automatic process running my file (.sh) from a cron job in cpanel administrator?

Comment: edit the script file to use `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`

Comment: Adding #!/usr/bin/expect -f quit the error i had but now sends me the this error `File "//home/dir/*20140120*.dat" not found.` Wildcards are not working.

Comment: what does the `spawn` command look like?

Comment: `spawn sftp -o IdentityFile=/home2/user/PrivKeys_open-file.ppk user@123.123.123.123`

Comment: I have solved that error adding `#!/usr/bin/expect -f` as yo said (that solved the error) and i have a really bad mistake. Instead of putting 
`send "mget /home/dir/*$date_file_format*.dat /home2/user/dir2 \r"` 
i put 
`send "mget *$date_file_format*.dat /home2/user/dir2 \r"` 
without the complete path to copy all files. Thanks man.